# Predict the number

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, loops, brute-force

I want the user to enter a 4 digit number and the program must tell what that 4 digit number was i.e generate that 4 digit number by Brute force attack.But at the line mentioned below the compiler says invalid indirection.I would also like to have some comments about they way I am implementing it,is it a good practise?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void BruteForceAttack(int *arr);
int main()
{
 int *arr,i;
 printf("Enter 4 digits ,press enter after entring each digit:\n");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 scanf("%d",arr+i);
 BruteForceAttack(arr);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
void BruteForceAttack(int *arr)
{
 int i,j,k,l;
 for(i=0;;i++)
 {
  for(j=0;;j++)
  {
   for(k=0;;k++)
   {
    for(l=0;;l++)
    {
      if((*(arr+0)==i)&&(*(arr+1==j))&&(*(arr+2==k))&&(*(arr+3)==l))   /*Here the compiler says invalid indirection*/
     {
      printf("The number is %d%d%d%d",i,j,k,l);
      return;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total of 3 problems:

**Problem 1:**

Your `arr` is a dangling pointer and you are dereferencing it in `scanf`.

You need:

```
int arr[4];
```

in place of

```
int *arr;
```

**Problem 2:**

The comparison involving `j` and `k` is incorrectly paranthesized:

```
&&(*(arr+1==j))&&(*(arr+2==k))
```

should be

```
&&(*(arr+1)==j)&&(*(arr+2)==k)
          ^              ^
```

**Problem 3:**

Even with above 2 fixes your program will run into *infinite loop*, because your `for` loops have *no terminating* conditions.

Since you are asking user to enter 4 digits, all your loop should go from `0` till `9` as:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        ^^^^^
```

Add similar check for other 3 loops aswell.

Answer (score 3):

> I would also like to have some
>   comments about they way I am
>   implementing it,is it a good practise?

With regards to this particular portion of your question, consider the algorithm you're trying to implement for a moment. You have the numbers available to you, stored in `arr`. If the user picks the number `9999` you will iterate through 10000 numbers before you reach it. Conversely, if you iterate through each digit one at a time and stop when you find the correct digit (since it is known beforehand) you iterate 40 times.

In terms of mathematical complexity, your current algorithm has a worst-case performance of 10<sup>n</sup>, whereas it could be implemented as 10n.

Comment: I actually want something like Brute-force to find what the numbers were,like we do to crack the passwords

Comment: @fahad: If it's a purely numerical password then you'll be able to implement faster algorithms by first converting the password to an integer, then. Unless you wanted to implement a dictionary attack or something of that sort (but then it's not really "brute force", I suppose). For example, though, you could implement a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Number_guessing_game) fairly easily on a numerical password.

Comment: I should probably add that a binary search also presumes you have a means of knowing if you're "greater" or "less than" the password. If you're strictly guessing via brute force (only yes/no responses) then your algorithm is pretty much how you'd have to do it. Hence why brute forcing a password takes an incredible amount of time and why longer passwords are more secure. Even with a number, each extra digit increases the worst-time performance by a factor of 10.

Comment: I was wondering how binary search algorithm could word with integer passwords as in it the numbers are first sorted in order.

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of problems:

1. You're not allocating any memory for `*arr`. Perhaps you should define `arr` as

   ```
   int arr[4];
   ```

   Then, in scanf, you can do something like:

   ```
   scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   ```
2. You can just use the array offsets notation on the problem line:

   ```
   if(arr[0] == i && arr[1] == j && arr[2] == k && arr[3] == l)
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Your parentheses are misplaced. `*(arr+1==j)` should be `*(arr+1)==j`, etc.  That will fix the compiler warning, but `arr[1]==j` (etc.) would be even better.

Comment: That is, of course, if you really really want to use pointer arithmetic -- somewhat pointless here. `*(arr+b)` is equivalent to `arr[b]`.

Comment: @Christian: Agreed!  But, coming from a Lisp background, I feel compelled to fix the parentheses...

Comment: How to make friends and influence people: Because `arr[b]` is equivalent to `*(arr + b)`, it's also equivalent to `*(b + arr)`, which is equivalent to `b[arr]`. So you can write array notation as `1[array]` and it will work the same as `array[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider your innermost loop

```
for(l=0;;l++)
    {
      if((*(arr+0)==i)&&(*(arr+1==j))&&(*(arr+2==k))&&(*(arr+3)==l))   /*Here the compiler says invalid indirection*/
     {
      printf("The number is %d%d%d%d",i,j,k,l);
      return;
     }
    }
```

If the number entered by the user is anything that is not staring with 000 - how will this loop ever get terminated? Will this not just go on looping infinitely for i, j, k ==0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't allocate any space for arr! Allocate the space using malloc.

```
...
int *arr,i;
arr = (int *) malloc(4*sizeof(int));
...
```

Also, you are converting a boolean (int in c) into an address! The braces are wrong in the line of error.

```
...
if((*(arr+0)==i)&&((*(arr+1)==j))&&((*(arr+2)==k))&&((*(arr+3)==l))
..
```